# Reverse for 'edit_review' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) error when editing comment

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms, django-templates

When i try to click on my edit comment button in product_detail i get this error and i cant figure out how to fix it.
would really appreciate some help thanks in advance.
error when clicking edit comment button below:
[image: error when clicking edit comment]

Am only writing out the needed code not the full code if there is anything u need tell me and i add.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, reverse, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.db.models import Q
from django.db.models.functions import Lower

from .models import Product, Category, Review
from .forms import ProductForm, ReviewForm


@login_required
def edit_review(request, review_id):
    review = get_object_or_404(Review, pk=review_id)
    product = Product.objects.get(name=review.product)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        review_form = ReviewForm(request.POST or None, instance=review)
        if review_form.is_valid():
            review_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Successfully updated Review!')
            return redirect(reverse('product_detail', args=[product.id]))
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Failed to update product. Please ensure the form is valid.')
    else:
        review_form = ReviewForm(instance=review)
        messages.info(request, f'You are editing {edit_review}')

    template = 'products/edit_review.html'
    context = {
        'review_form': review_form,
        'Review': Review,
    }

    return render(request, template, context)
```

**Models.py**

```
class Review(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='reviews', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=3)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='reviews', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.product.name, self.created_by)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .widgets import CustomClearableFileInput
from .models import Product, Category, Review


class ReviewForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = ('content', 'rating')
        widgets = {
            'content': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'rating': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control',}),
        }
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.all_products, name='products'),
    path('<int:product_id>/', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),
    path('add/', views.add_product, name='add_product'),
    path('edit/<int:product_id>/', views.edit_product, name='edit_product'),
    path('delete/<int:product_id>/', views.delete_product, name='delete_product'),
    path('delete_review/<int:review_id>/delete_review', views.delete_review, name='delete-review'),
    path('edit_review/<review_id>', views.edit_review, name="edit_review"),
]
```

**edit_review.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}


{% block content %}
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                <hr>
                <h2 class="logo-font mb-4">Reviews</h2>
                <h5 class="text-muted">Edit you're Review</h5>
                <hr>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                <form method="POST" action="{% url 'edit_review' review.id %}" class="form mb-2" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {% for field in form %}
                        {% if field.name != 'image' %}
                            {{ field | as_crispy_field }}
                        {% else %}
                            {{ field }}
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                    <div class="text-right">
                        <a class="btn btn-outline-black rounded-0" href="{% url 'reviews' %}">Cancel</a>
                        <button class="btn btn-black rounded-0" type="submit">Update Review</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**product_detail.html**

```
{% for review in reviews %}
            <div class="container">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <img src="https://image.ibb.co/jw55Ex/def_face.jpg" class="img img-rounded img-fluid" alt="Profile picture"/>
                                <p class="text-secondary text-center">{{ review.created_at|date:"Y-m-d" }}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <p>
                                    <a class="float-left" style="color:blue"><strong>{{ review.created_by }}</a>
                                    <span class="float-right"><i class="text-warning fa fa-star">{{ review.rating }}/5</i></span>
                               </p>
                               <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                <p>{{ review.content }}</p>
                                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                                {% if user.id == review.created_by.id %}
                                <p>
                                    <a a href="{% url 'edit_review' review.id %}" class="float-right btn btn-primary ml-2 text-white"> <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</a>
                                    <a href="{% url 'delete-review' review.id %}" class="float-right btn text-white btn-danger"> <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</a>
                               </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            
                                </div>
                            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the context, you used 'Review' and in the template you are using 'review.id' which is None, unify the keys and it shall work.

Comment: I changed them so they had the same name name but still same error.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your `edit_review`. You named object lowercase `review`. So in context you are not passing an object, but actually `Review` class. So `Review.id == None` and it cannot create proper `{% url 'edit_review' ... %}` from that. Another thing, in context you are also naming it uppercase, which you shouldn't. So basically you don't pass `'review'` context at all.

```
@login_required
def edit_review(request, review_id):
    review = get_object_or_404(Review, pk=review_id)   
    (...)
    context = {
        'review_form': review_form,
        'Review': Review,
    }
```

So the thing you need to change, is this:

```
    context = {
        ...
        'Review': Review,  ===>   'review': review,
    }
```